# Public Enum / class could not be accessed / found

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, enums

In my ASP.NET project, I have an App_Code folder.

In the folder are several classes that work perfectly fine. The classes can see each other without any problems.

I have also added an Enums.cs file to the folder. The Enums.cs file contains the following code:

```
namespace xsite.App_Code
{
  public enum Bottle
  {
    Glass,
    Plastic,
    Paper
  }
}
```

Problem is that none of the classes in the folder can use the Bottle enum. When I try to use the enum, I get the following error:

*The type or namespace name 'Bottle' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)*

The namespace of the classes in the folder is the same as the enum.

Any idea how I can fix this, so I can use the Bottle enum?

Comment: Can you post a minimal class that cannot see it? `class Test{private Bottle _bottle;}`. Is `Bottle` a part of your project? Are you sure it is being deployed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you could not access the enum by xsite.App_Code.Bottle then you have to check the properties of the file. Right click the file and take properties. There will be a property called `Build Action`, set it to `Compile`.

[image]

Comment: Perfect. That was the problem, the build action was set to Content for some reason.

Answer (score 1):

Try to use xsite.App_Code.Bottle

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that the calling class uses or is in the same namespace as the bottles enum class. Look in your class view to see.

Answer (score 0):

For newbies - like me - who are reading this and do NOT have the OP's problem and solution... What the OP did *should* have worked and the critical elements of making it work are:

1. Put the namespace declaration in a file in the App_Code folder, NOT
   a code-behind file.  (It is not necessary to include 'App_code' in
   that namespace)
2. Make sure the enum declaration is 'public'
3. Put a 'using myNamespace;' declaration in your code-behind files

The pattern I am going to use going forward is something like below because I feel it will be the easiest way for me to: Use the enum names I want; Give the access I need; Keep everything in one place for maintainability; And give sufficient isolation between apps to keep me out of trouble.  Should also be scalable if my one man team ever grows.

In App_Code\SiteEnums.cs:

```
namespace SiteGlobalEnums
{
  public enum SiteWideValues1
  {
    value1, value1, value3
  }

  public enum SiteWideValues2
  {
    value1, value1, value3
  }
}

namespace AppName1Enums
{
  public enum AppName1Values1
  {
    value1, value1, value3
  }

  public enum AppName1Values2
  {
    value1, value1, value3
  }
}

namespace AppName2Enums
{
  public enum AppName2Values1
  {
    value1, value1, value3
  }

  public enum AppName2Values2
  {
    value1, value1, value3
  }
}
```

In code-behind pages:

```
using SiteGlobalEnums;
using AppName1Enums;  // etc. as needed for apps
```